# Disable auto-close HTML tagging in FreeTextBox for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, tags, freetextbox

Recently I have run into a bit of a problem with FreeTextBox for ASP.NET. Every time I open a HTML tag in the HTML editor view, if I switch to the design view and come back the tag is automatically closed. This happens when pasting text into the box as well. This is a real problem, I don't want the tag to close automatically, is there any method that can be used to stop this I have looked through the documentation but can't find anything to prevent auto-closing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you that, sometime, the answer is "No, you can't do that".

The only way can I see to do this is by altering the source code. There's a Distribution License that allow you download and modify the code to fit your needs, but there is no easy way out.